# Topological dimension of closed sphere

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

How can one show that the topological dimension (Lebesgue covering dimension) of the closed $n$-dimensional unit ball $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid 1\geq|x|\}$ is indeed $n$, assuming only that:

- the topological dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ equals $n$.
- the topological dimension of  open $n$-dimensional unit ball $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid 1>|x|\}$ equals $n$.
- the topological dimension is invariant under homeomorphism.

I know that this can be shown using the small and large inductive dimensions $ind$ and $Ind$. But is there a way that minimises the need for theoretical background knowledge and only uses above assumptions?

---

My approach was to show that each finite open cover and its refinement of the open unit ball could be extended by a tiny enlargement to a cover and its refinement of the closed ball and thus show that the dimensions of open and closed balls are equal. However, I think that this fails because not all finite open covers of the open ball have an equivalent for the closed ball.

---

**Edit:** Additional assumption:

- Let $A$ be a closed subset of the metric space $S$. Then $\dim(A)\leq\dim(S)$

Comment: This gives that the dimension of the closed ball is at most $n$.  To show that it is $n$, then you have to show that every cover has a refinement of order at least $n+1$.  But to cover the closed unit ball, you have to cover a slightly smaller open ball, and every open cover of the open ball has a refinement of order no smaller than $n+1$.  Why doesn't this do the job?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Because there are covers of the inner open ball which are not extensible to the larger closed ball without adding additional open sets. So it might be that exactly those covers which cannot be extended are those that make the order $n+1$ necessary. But they do not necessarily

Comment: But as you add open sets, the *worst* thing that can happen is that you get more overlapping (you cannot reduce the overlapping by adding more sets).  Hence this gives a *lower* bound on the dimension.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot!